# Adding point layer information (point id) after "Split Lines at Points" to the newly split line layer

Tags: qgis, point, line, splitting

I have a point layer for a group of roads and a line layer (have directions) for the roads. I need to calculate the distance between two adjacent points on the line layer hence I was thinking of splitting the line layer by the point layer to calculate the distance of the newly formed segments to solve my problem. However, I have a issue that I want to add the newly line segments layer the two points that form it into its attribute table. If possible, I will also like to maintain the information of which is the point is the start and which point is the end for the line segment.

I am using QGIS for this task as for some license reason, my ArcGIS Pro don't have access to the "Split Lines at Points" function in the software.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing the data